# Efficient way to count the digits of very big factorials

Tags: java, factorial

Suppose that we have a very large factorial such as (10^7)!, Is there an efficient way to count its **exact** digits? (Wolfram alpha result says (10^7)! has 65,657060 digits)

Of course, I can't use the naive implementation by successively multiplying the value one by one since it will be too slow to evaluate the result.

I think the solution to this question might ended up in either

1. How to find the digit of the factorial without calculating the factorial
2. How to compute the factorial more efficiently (BigInteger or BigDecimal is preferable)

I would prefer 1. rather than 2. since I just want to know how many digits of the factorial.
Any suggestion?

Comment: I think this is more of a math question than a programming question. I haven't tried it, but a quick google search found this: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/68245.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to work out how many bits the result of a factorial should take up as a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583169/how-to-work-out-how-many-bits-the-result-of-a-factorial-should-take-up-as-a-numb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding up the logs of all the numbers you would multiply by should do the trick:

```
public long facDigits(long n) {
    double logFacN = 0;
    for (long i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        logFacN += Math.log10(i);
    }
    return (long) logFacN + 1;
}

public void test() {
    double tenToThe7th = Math.pow(10, 7);
    long digits = facDigits((long) tenToThe7th);
    System.out.println("Digits in " + tenToThe7th + "! = " + digits);
}
```

prints

```
Digits in 1.0E7! = 65657060
```

The logic here is that as you multiply by `x` while calculating the factorial you are actually adding `log10(x)` digits so here I just add those up.

Comment: At least it doesn't need BigInteger memory hogging.

Comment: This is only as accurate as your log calculations are

Comment: @KevinL - You are correct - but it does seem to perform effectively up to 10^7! which I was surprised at. It is certainly quicker than calculating `log10(10^7!)`. It gets the answer in 1.356s on my rig.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon a double gives you 15 digits precision, which once you convert to log calculations, since your answer is 8 digits, you have about 7 digits to use for rounding, which apparently is close enough

Comment: This is almost 100% correct. You should 1 to the result, since # of digits is calculated by `floor(log(N))+1`. The `floor` is done by the cast to `long`, and the log of a product equals the sum of the logs of the summands, which you calculate in your loop. You're just short of the `+1`

Answer (score 0):

@OldCurmudgeon's solution is good but you can try to use Kamentsky's formula:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int numOfTests = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        in.lines()
                .limit(numOfTests)
                .map(n -> Integer.parseInt(n))
                .forEach(n -> System.out.println(KamenetskyFormula(n)));
    }

    private static long KamenetskyFormula(int n) {
        if (n < 2) {
            return 1;
        }
        double x = n * Math.log10(n / Math.E) + Math.log10(2 * Math.PI * n) / 2.0;
        return (long) (Math.floor(x) + 1);
    }
}
```

connected to [Count number of digits in factorial - performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67598118/count-number-of-digits-in-factorial-performance-issue)

Comment: Nice and fast, but Kamenetsky formula gives **approximate** result and can fail for some numbers