# Count number of digits in factorial - Input/Ouput performance issue

Tags: java, algorithm, math, optimization, factorial

I am solving task on spoj platform - count number of digits in factorial.
I found Kamenetsky Formula and implemented it:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int numOfTests = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        for(int i = 0; i < numOfTests; i++) {
            System.out.println(KamenetskyFormula(Integer.parseInt(in.readLine())));
        }

        /*
        in.lines()
                .limit(numOfTests)
                .map(n -> Integer.parseInt(n))
                .forEach(n -> System.out.println(KamenetskyFormula(n)));*/
    }

    private static long KamenetskyFormula(int n) {
        if (n < 2) {
            return 1;
        }
        double x = n * Math.log10(n / Math.E) + Math.log10(2 * Math.PI * n) / 2.0;
        return (long) (Math.floor(x) + 1);
    }
}
```

first I used commented code (streams) and as I thought it's slower than actual one (without comments) so I changed but still getting exceed time limit. How can I make it faster?

Example input is (first line is number of tests):

```
3
1
10
100
```

and expected output:

```
1
7
158
```

Comment: I don't see much room for improvement in this code. Using some log identities and precalculations the formula could be written in a form that requires only one log calculation instead of two. But for a low number of test cases this would not matter much. Maybe there is some other method that is more efficient.

Comment: How fast does it need to be? I did a quick check and your code completed (approximately) instantly, even when adding 1000 to the bunch.

Comment: @Yonas
Limit czasu wykonania programu: 0.303s which means, 
Program execution timeout : 0.303s

I checked history of solutions of this task and one guy solved it in Java, so somehow it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the time limit is exceeding because of the slow I/O. This is mainly because of System.out.println's underlying PrintStream. Find more details in this post [why-is-system-out-println-so-slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437715/why-is-system-out-println-so-slow). You can refer to the below Fast I/O template which will help solve this problem.

Reference  - [Fast I/O in java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fast-io-in-java-in-competitive-programming/)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class YourClassName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream inputStream = System.in;
        OutputStream outputStream = System.out;
        InputReader in = new InputReader(inputStream);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
        TaskA solver = new TaskA();
        int testCount = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
        for (int i = 1; i <= testCount; i++)
            solver.solve(i, in, out);
        out.close();
    }

    static class TaskA {
        public void solve(int testNumber, InputReader sc, PrintWriter w) {
            /*your logic goes here
            use w.println here to print the output which is usually faster
            */
        }

    }

    static class InputReader {
        private InputStream stream;
        private byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        private int curChar;
        private int numChars;
        private InputReader.SpaceCharFilter filter;

        public InputReader(InputStream stream) {
            this.stream = stream;
        }

        public int read() {
            if (numChars == -1)
                throw new InputMismatchException();

            if (curChar >= numChars) {
                curChar = 0;
                try {
                    numChars = stream.read(buf);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                }

                if (numChars <= 0)
                    return -1;
            }
            return buf[curChar++];
        }

        public int nextInt() {
            int c = read();

            while (isSpaceChar(c))
                c = read();

            int sgn = 1;

            if (c == '-') {
                sgn = -1;
                c = read();
            }

            int res = 0;
            do {
                if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                res *= 10;
                res += c - '0';
                c = read();
            } while (!isSpaceChar(c));

            return res * sgn;
        }

        public long nextLong() {
            int c = read();
            while (isSpaceChar(c))
                c = read();
            int sgn = 1;
            if (c == '-') {
                sgn = -1;
                c = read();
            }
            long res = 0;

            do {
                if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                res *= 10;
                res += c - '0';
                c = read();
            } while (!isSpaceChar(c));
            return res * sgn;
        }

        public String readString() {
            int c = read();
            while (isSpaceChar(c))
                c = read();
            StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
            do {
                res.appendCodePoint(c);
                c = read();
            } while (!isSpaceChar(c));

            return res.toString();
        }

        public boolean isSpaceChar(int c) {
            if (filter != null)
                return filter.isSpaceChar(c);
            return c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == '\t' || c == -1;
        }

        public String next() {
            return readString();
        }

        public interface SpaceCharFilter {
            public boolean isSpaceChar(int ch);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly even with:
`static class TaskA {
        public void solve(InputReader sc, PrintWriter writer) {
            writer.println(KamenetskyFormula(Integer.parseInt(sc.next())));
        }
    }` 

there is still time limit exceed ;/

Comment: Shouldn't you use ```sc.nextLong()``` instead of ```sc.next()``` ?  Because reading a string and converting to Integer is an overhead

Comment: it did the job! Thank you @Darshil Dave!

`writer.println(KamenetskyFormula(sc.nextLong()));`